# Why can't shell code in Meteor run well on server?

Tags: node.js, shell, meteor

I make my meteor app run a shell code(like mkdir foo) well in my Mac,but when I deploy it on my VPS,it can't run.I use Meteor and MUP to deploy it.Now I don't know how to debug it on my VPS.

Here come to the DEMO code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({
      setBlogList: function(){
        var run = Npm.require('child_process');
        run.exec('mkdir ~/memeda');
    }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "it can't run"? What error message do you get, if any?

If the code fails to create the directory, it's probably because the user mup runs it under doesn't have write access to whatever it thinks the home directory is.

Use [`path.resolve('~/memeda')`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) to see what that directory actually resolves to in the filesystem, and go from there. Look in the [mup documentation](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#example-file) for how to set paths (e.g. the `app` setting).